# Paperclip plugin : Change image folder permissions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, permissions, ruby-on-rails-plugins, paperclip

By default when I upload new images, the folder created have 777
permissions
Is there a way to restrict permissions on the new folders?

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Other way you can do this by changing in the paperclip plugin itself.

Change the permission as you want in the below file of paperclip plugin
/lib/paperclip/storage.rb